# Python Regex Expression Needed to Add Only a 2nd Backslash

Tags: python, python-re

I have an expression that works in sed and need to adopt it for python. I want to insert a backslash next to each "single" backslash. For clarity here, I am replacing an isolated backslash with an "X". Here is what works in sed. Remember that sed actually sees the input as aaa\bbb\ccc. I would like the output to be "aaa\bbb\ccc".

```
echo "aaa\\bbb\\\\ccc" | sed -e 's/\([^\\]\)\\\([^\\]\)/\1X\2/'
```

I tried a few things like:

```
re.sub("([^\\])\\([^\\])", "\1X\2", r"123\456\\789")
r"123\456\\789".replace(r"([^\])\([^\])", "\1X\2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `r` notation also for the other arguments that you pass to `re.sub` -- that way the string goes as-is (with all backslashes) to the regex engine (which uses backslash escaping also).

So:

```
s = re.sub(r"([^\\])\\([^\\])", r"\1X\2", r"123\456\\789")
```

Or, with `X` replaced with two literal backslashes:

```
s = re.sub(r"([^\\])\\([^\\])", r"\1\\\\\2", r"123\456\\789")
```

There is a boundary case where this regular expression does not do the job right (if I understand your purpose correctly): when the isolated backslash is the very first or very last character in the string, it will not be doubled. If you need that to happen, use look-around:

```
s = re.sub(r"(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)", r"\\\\", r"123\456\\789")
```

Comment: I didn't see your rsponse until it refreshed after I posted. Sorry. Looks like we agree on teh solution.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force and I figured it out. I'll need to look at it some more to figure out why.

```
re.sub(r"([^\\])\\([^\\])", r"\1x\2", r"aaa\bbb\\ccc")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).